# $\cos (x)= -0.7, 2π ≤ x < 4π$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the answer for this, but my teacher hadn't taught the whole "when cosine is an even, the value of $-\arccos (-0.7)$ is a solution too."

Please:

-tell me when a $\cos$/$\sin$ function is even/odd

-what happens if its odd?

-how to use the "$±\arccos(-0.7) + 2kπ$" ( don't understand why you add 2kπ)

-and how to find the solutions!

Another example is $$\sec( x )= -3, -π ≤ x < π $$

I really don't understand what happens if the function is "even" or "odd." And how to determine if it is.

Comment: A function $f(x)$ is called "even" if $f(-x) = f(x)$ and "odd" if $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

Comment: $0.7\approx\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ . Now, the sine and cosine of which angle equals $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Even and odd functions**

- *Even functions*: $f(x)=f(-x)$. Geometrically, this is symmetry about the $y$-axis.
- *Odd functions*: $-f(x)=f(-x)$. Geometrically, this is origin symmetry.

From these definitions and the graphs of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, we can see that $\sin x$ is odd, $\cos x$ even.

[image]

Note: ${\color{red} \sin \color{red}x}$ is red, $\color{blue}\cos \color{blue}x$ is blue.

Answer (score 0):

I restrict to a solution of the title of your question.

In general $\cos x=\cos\alpha$ if and only if $\frac{x-\alpha}{2\pi}$
is an integer or $\frac{x+\alpha}{2\pi}$ is an integer.

Another way
to express that is: if and only if $x=\pm\alpha+2k\pi$ where $k$
stands for an integer. Take notice of sign $\pm$.

If you have equation $\cos x=-0.7$ then this can be used.
To find is some $\alpha$ that satisfies $\cos\alpha=-0.7$ and here
function $\arccos$ comes in: $\cos\alpha=-0.7$ is true for $\alpha=\arccos\left(-0.7\right)$.

This leads to $x=\pm\arccos\left(-0.7\right)+2k\pi$ and as last step
you must find all integers $k$ that satisfy $\arccos\left(-0.7\right)+2k\pi\in[2\pi,4\pi)$
or $-\arccos\left(-0.7\right)+2k\pi\in[2\pi,4\pi)$.

This solves the equation $\cos x=-0.7$ under the extra condition that
$x\in[2\pi,4\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a function $f(x)$ is called even if $f(-x) = f(x)$ and odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

We add $2k\pi$ to the answer because both sine and cosine are periodic of period $2\pi$.  To see this, you can think of sine and cosine as the $x$ and $y$ values respectively of a point on the circumference of the unit circle:
[image: Sine and Cosine on the unit circle.]

Notice that once we go around the circle by $2\pi$, all the $x$ and $y$ values are repeated.  Hence, for any equation like $\cos(x) = -0.7$, there are an infinite number of answers.  However the "primary" answers all occur within a $2\pi$ window, all other answers are in some sense duplicates of these answers (they correspond to the same points on the unit circle, but after having gone around the circle more than once).

The value of $\arccos(-0.7)$ is defined to be **unique** value of $x$ between $0$ and $\pi$ such that $\cos(x) = -0.7$. There is another solution to this equation on the bottom half of the circle ($\pi$ to $2\pi$ or $0$ to $-\pi$).    This is where odd and even functions come in.  Because cosine is even, $cos(-x) = cos(x)$, so we know that if $\cos(x) = =0.7$, $\cos(-x) = -0.7$ as well.

To get all the other infinitely many answers to the problem, we can add multiples of $2\pi$ to our original two answers.  This is why the general solution is of the problem has $2k\pi$ added.